# In highchart of column type and xaxis of datetime type showing more ticks for month data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When I plot column chart using highcharts with a month of data there is an extra tick getting added in the end.

I have data from 14th April to 14th May whereas x-axis shows 15th May there is no data for 15th May which is actually a future date.

https://jsfiddle.net/kamaldeka/Lex25cp3/
[image]

The same problem is not seen if I use the line/spline chart.

https://jsfiddle.net/kamaldeka/et21ykrx/
[image]

The data are real-time so I need to keep `time.useUTC` to false.

Comment: Hi @Kamal Deka, I checked your examples and it seems that the `xAxis` labels are the same.

Comment: @ppotaczek are you sure? I just checked column chart has one extra ends on 15 May at and spline chart ends on 14 May.

Comment: I get the same result as @ppotaczek. Both graphs show 14. May as the last date.

Comment: Just tested in IE 10, Chrome 74, Firefox 66, Edge 18 and the last value is 14 May.

Comment: Little strange as I am getting different result i have updated the question with images too. I am seeing similar issue in codepen too. I guess the result same in UTC timezone.

Comment: This is happening if the timezone is UTC+5:30 or more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `pointPlacement` property to `'on'`:

> **pointPlacement:** string, number
>
> Possible values: "on","between", number.
>
> In a column chart, when pointPlacement is "on", the point will not
>   create any padding of the X axis. (...)

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        pointPlacement: 'on',
        ...
    }
}
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/169j4q8o/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.pointPlacement